# Why is XmlSerializer's Deserialize calling my class constructor twice?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xmlserializer

I'm using this code:

```
using (Stream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    XmlSerializer xmlFormatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Project));
    result = (Project)xmlFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

to deserialize my `Project` class. Inside that class there is another class called `DataBaseManager` that is defined this way:

```
private DataBaseManager _DataBase = new DataBaseManager();
```

`DataBaseManager` implements `IDisposable` and **needs** to be disposed for each time is created. But for some reason `Deserialize` is creating a `DataBaseManager` twice and not disposing any of them (of course one of them must not be disposed because is the one I'll use).

Here is the call stack for the first call:

```
HS Dll.exe!Player.DataBaseManager.DataBaseManager() Line 42 C#
HS Dll.exe!Player.Project.BasicProject.BasicProject() Line 108 + 0x15 bytes C#
HS Dll.exe!WebScraperAndPlayer.Project.Project() Line 23 + 0x8 bytes    C#
xdowmsmh!Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderProject.Read32_Project(bool isNullable, bool checkType) + 0x178 bytes  
xdowmsmh!Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderProject.Read33_Project() + 0xb8 bytes  
[Native to Managed Transition]  
System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.InvokeReader(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlMapping mapping, System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlDeserializationEvents events, string encodingStyle) + 0xc1 bytes 
System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader, string encodingStyle, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlDeserializationEvents events) + 0xc8 bytes
```

And this is the second call:

```
HS Dll.exe!Player.DataBaseManager.DataBaseManager() Line 42 C#
xdowmsmh!Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderProject.Read32_Project(bool isNullable, bool checkType) + 0x2a53 bytes 
xdowmsmh!Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderProject.Read33_Project() + 0xb8 bytes  
[Native to Managed Transition]  
System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.InvokeReader(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlMapping mapping, System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlDeserializationEvents events, string encodingStyle) + 0xc1 bytes 
System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader, string encodingStyle, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlDeserializationEvents events) + 0xc8 bytes
```

Also, `DataBaseManager` implements `IXmlSerializable`, but `ReadXml` is only called after both `DataBaseManager` have been created, so I don't think I'm doing anything wrong there.

Comment: This is an "active" object, in that it creates an `IDisposable` instance. This isn't the sort of thing you should be serializing and deserializing, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the `Project` class have a public property which would expose the `_DataBase` field to the serializer?

The XmlSerializer will instantiate a new `DataBaseManager` object and deserialize it completely before assigning it back to your `Project` object (through the public property).

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I'll have to dispose the old `DataBaseManager` in the setter. And make sure the same isn't happening in any other class in the whole project!

Comment: Wait. I think that's not right. If class A has a property B that needs to be disposed, who should be responsible for disposing B? I would think whoever creates it but XmlSerializer won't do that....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a constructor for the Project type creates an instance of DataBaseManager.

In your case the constructor of Project creates one instance of DataBaseManager when an instance of the Project type is deserialized. Then another instance DataBaseManager is created by the deserializer that deserializes one of Project fields.

Comment: You probably need to mark a field that holds your DataBaseManager object with NonSerializableAttribute. Then it will be created only by the Project class constructor and will not be created second time by deserializer.

Comment: One correction. Due to the stack DataBasaManager is created by ProjectBase constructor that is called by Project constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you have exposed the `DataBaseManager` via a public property then the XmlSerializer will create and deserialize it as Sam said. Now the first time the `DataBaseManager` is created it's apparently done in the constructor of `BasicProject`. When the serializer tries to deserialize the project class it calls the default constructor which apparently creates a database manager.